# помогите решить ошибку list indices must be integers or slices, not PollOption

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

мой код

```
async def check_polls_in_chat(client, message):
    if message.chat.id == -1001998251987:  
        if message.poll:
            poll_id = message.poll.id
            options = message.poll.options
            result = {}

            for option in options:  
                result[option.text] = option.voter_count

            
            correct_option_id = options[0]
            
            await message.vote(correct_option_id)
            

            await client.send_message(-1001772397440, f"correct_option_id: {correct_option_id}")

@app.on_message(filters.chat(-1001998251987))
async def handle_message(client, message):
    await check_polls_in_chat(client, message)
app.run()
```

после запуска и отправки опроса в канал с айди -1001998251987 в терминале выдает ошибку

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not PollOption
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\dispatcher.py", line 240, in handler_worker
    await handler.callback(self.client, *args)
  File "C:\pythonscripts\kek\gg.py", line 31, in handle_message
    await check_polls_in_chat(client, message)
  File "C:\pythonscripts\kek\gg.py", line 24, in check_polls_in_chat
    await message.vote(correct_option_id)
  File "C:\Users\VPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\types\messages_and_media\message.py", line 3519, in vote
    return await self._client.vote_poll(
  File "C:\Users\VPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\messages\vote_poll.py", line 65, in vote_poll
    options=[poll.options[option].data for option in options]
  File "C:\Users\VPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyrogram\methods\messages\vote_poll.py", line 65, in <listcomp>
    options=[poll.options[option].data for option in options]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not PollOption
```

Comment: Покажите полный стек-трейс ошибки в вопросе. Данный код такую ошибку дать не может.

Comment: @CrazyElf изменил вопрос

Comment: Похоже что в `correct_option_id` у вас не `id` опции, а сама опция. От неё ещё нужно `id` как-то взять. Как именно - смотрите документацию, я не в курсе. Может быть так: `correct_option_id = options[0].id`, но не уверен.

Comment: @CrazyElf теперь AttributeError: 'PollOption' object has no attribute 'id'

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто смотреть [документацию](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/Poll)

`correct_option_id` нужно брать из `message.poll`, а не из `options`

```
correct_option_id = message.poll.correct_option_id
```